# home-manager how to set gnome dark mode?

Tags: gtk, gnome

I'm trying out home-manager for the first time, and was trying to use it set Gnome to use dark mode. So I set both qt and gtk theme to dark:

```
qt.enable = true;
qt.style.name = "adwaita-dark";
gtk.enable = true;
gtk.theme.name = "Adwaita-dark";
```

Which works for most applications, but doesn't for Gnome Files (Nautilus) even though, as far as I know, it's a GTK application. Also does not work after rebooting.

Does anybody know why this is happening? And how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the `dconf.settings`, which is  what worked! I had to set the following:

```
dconf.settings = {
  "org/gnome/desktop/interface" = {
    color-scheme = "prefer-dark";
  };
  ...
```